# Update button in previous view controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I'm using a NavigationController to show a list of followers of a certain user. In this list (a UITableView), there is the profile picture, the username and on the far right is a follow or unfollow button.

I have managed to implement a function that checks if the user is following already, so it clearly shows follow or unfollow as it should. I am also able to update the button after a user starts following the other user and the same goes for unfollowing.

However, it is possible to click on the username or on the profile picture after which I push the NavigationController to the profile of the user that was clicked.

```
navViewController?.pushViewController(userVC, animated: true)
```

On the profile page is the same follow or unfollow button, with the same logic (but slightly adapted as I don't need indexPaths on the profile page etc). Everything works, except when I go to someone's profile page from the list, start following or unfollow and use the back button on my NavigationController to go back to the list. It still shows the text from before and applies the wrong logic (if I unfollow on a profile, go back and unfollow in the list (which shouldn't be possible, but the button is not updated yet) I create a double unfollow, sort of speak.

I am looking for a way to update the button on the previous view (the UITableView). Any ideas? I can not use .observe instead of .observeSingleEvent as this will create a loop of following and unfollowing, because my code to get the list is as follows:

```
func getUsers() {

    var Ref: DatabaseReference!
    Ref = Database.database().reference()

    Ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "userLastName").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshotUsers) in

        for child in snapshotUsers.children {

            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]

            if(snap.key != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) {
                Ref.child("users").child(snap.key).child("userFollowers").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (checkFollow) in

                    if checkFollow.exists() {

                        self.myArray.append(usersToFollow(userID: snap.key, userName: (dict["userFirstName"] as! String) + " " + (dict["userLastName"] as! String), userFirstName: (dict["userFirstName"] as! String), userLastName: (dict["userLastName"] as! String), userProfilePicURL: (dict["userProfilePicURL"] as! String), isFollowing: true))

                    } else {

                        self.myArray.append(usersToFollow(userID: snap.key, userName: (dict["userFirstName"] as! String) + " " + (dict["userLastName"] as! String), userFirstName: (dict["userFirstName"] as! String), userLastName: (dict["userLastName"] as! String), userProfilePicURL: (dict["userProfilePicURL"] as! String), isFollowing: false))

                    }

                    self.myTableView.reloadData()

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Any help on how to resolve this problem in my UITableView would be appreciated!

Comment: you can call this `getUsers()` method in `viewDidAppear()` of the _List ViewController_

Comment: That’s correct. I had implemented this before asking this question, and it works, however by reloading alone I coudn’t achieve the result I wanted - I had to removeAll() from my array and call getUsers() again in viewWillAppear. The problem is that it flickers briefly and goes to the top of the tableview (as all records are deleted and loaded in again), which would not be nice if you’re going through a list of 250 users and have to start at the top again every time. Which is why I’m wondering if there is a better solution..

Comment: See , what I think you can do to avoid reloading all the rows is that , when a _user_ navigates to another profile from _List ViewController_ , you can temporarily record the `IndexPath` of that row in a variable , and if the user changes the state of the _Follow/Unfollow_ via clicking the `button`, you can create a separate `protocol` and make your  _List ViewController_  conform to that and provide a _method_ inside the _protocol_ which updates a single row based on `IndexPath` (which we recorded earlier). Now this _method_ will be called when the user clicks the _Follow/Unfollow_ button

Comment: For that you need to learn **How to pass data between ViewControllers using protocol**

Comment: Could I achieve it by adding an optional variable in which I set the row of the cell, then check if it’s set on the profile when following or unfollowing and updating the button in the row that was sent? Or is this not possible?

Comment: See, it's more or less the _same thing_, you still have to pass the data between `ViewControllers` using one way to other . What I can recommend , _an easier way_, apart from using protocol, would be using a `UserDefaults` which act as your _Persistent Storage_ . You can use it to pass information between  `ViewControllers` and _adding to_ as well as _removing from_ `UserDefaults` according to your logic i.e. when you switch between _View Controllers_

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it using NSNotification to call your tableView.reloadData():
add this to ur tableView Controller's (TVC) ViewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

and this function to ur TVC

```
@objc func reload()
{
      //setup ur new data
      self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

then just add to ur back button IBAction in user's pf VC

```
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

Comment: The thing is, I don’t feel comfortable reloading the data as I want to keep the same list as before, but edit the button and its action set to it. I have now implemented a way to do it by checking if there is a previous controller and if there is, the button in the cell is updated. Still testing, but it seems to work fine for now.

Comment: so you can keep the index of selected user in ur users list before navigating, and then in the pf VC , send the status (following/not following) by notification , and in @objc func reload() instead of reloading the whole table view just update the button( because u now have both the index and the status)